# Airflow - is depends_on_past and trigger_rule the same?

Tags: airflow

In airflow.models.BaseOperator. You have two default parameter:

`depends_on_past=False` and `trigger_rule=u'all_success'`

According to doc

> depends_on_past (bool) – when set to true, task instances will run sequentially while relying on the previous task’s schedule to succeed.
>
> trigger_rule (str) – defines the rule by which dependencies are applied for the task to get triggered.

Isn't both the same thing ? I don't get why there are redundant parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, both are entirely different. depends_on_past(boolean) is for to check whether to run a task or not depending on its previous DAG run(last run). trigger_rule is used to trigger a task depends on its parent task(s) state.

refer [offical document](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules)